# Sum of Prime numbers

Tags: php

I have the following code, to output all prime numbers from array. I would like to get the sum of the output in ex: 2+3+5 = 10, Any hint how to get that ?

```
$n = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

function prime($n){


    for($i=0;$i<= count($n);$i++){

        $counter = 0; 
        for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){ 

            if($i % $j==0){ 

                $counter++;
            }
        }

        if($counter == 2){

            print $i."<br/>";
        }
    }
}


print prime($n);
```

Comment: Do you want the String: `2+3+5 = 10` as an output or just the sum `10`?

Comment: `$sum += $i` or maybe `$list[] = $i` and `$sum = array_sum($list);`

Comment: [Possible duplicate...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproject-euler%5D+"%2310")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then this should work for you:

(Here i used `$sum` which i initialized before the `foreach` loop and then used the `+=` operator to add the sum together)

```
<?php

    $n = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

    function prime($n){
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($n as $k => $v) {
            $counter = 0; 
            for($j = 1; $j <= $v; $j++) { 
                if($v % $j == 0)
                    $counter++;

            }

            if($counter == 2) {
                echo $v."<br/>";
                $sum += $v;
            }

        }
        echo "Sum: " . $sum;

    }

    prime($n);


?>
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
Sum: 10
```

Comment: surely will :D, you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function isPrime($n){
    if($n == 1) return false;
    if($n == 2) return true;
    for($x = 2; $x <= sqrt($n); $x++){
        if($n % $x == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$sum = 0;
$n = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($n as $val){
    if(isPrime($val)) {
        echo $val . "<br />";
        $sum += $val;
    }
}
echo "Sum: " . $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @IMSoP commented above, one option is to compile the list of primes into a new array:

```
$m = [];

// looping code...

// If prime:
array_push( $m, $primeNumber );
```

Then, when you're done, you can do your printing mechanism:

```
print implode( "<br />", $m );
```

And then you can do your summing mechanism:

```
print "<p>Sum: " . array_sum( $m ) . "</p>";
```

The added benefit here is you can split out each piece of functionality into it's own function or method (which you should do to have a good design).

Comment: I've never really understood why people use `array_push` in simple cases where `$foo[] =` would make sense. I guess it's just taste, but it always feels ... un-PHP-ish.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

define('N', 200);

function isPrime($num) 
{
    if ($num == 2 || $num == 3) { return 1; }
    if (!($num%2) || $num<1)    { return 0; }

    for ($n = 3; $n <= $num/2; $n += 2) {
        if (!($num%$n)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

for ($i = 2; $i <= N; $i++) {
    if (isPrime($i)) {
        $sum += $i;
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

    $num = 100;
    for($j=2;$j<$num;$j++)
    {
            for($k=2;$k<$j;$k++)
            {
                    if($j%$k==0)
                    {
                      break;
                    }

            }
            if($k==$j)
            {
                    $prime_no[]=$j;
            }

    }

    echo  "<pre>";
    print_r($prime_no);
    echo  "</pre>";
    for($j=0;$j<count($prime_no);$j++)
    {
            $myprimeAdd = $prime_no[$j] + $prime_no[$j+1];
            if(in_array($myprimeAdd,$prime_no))
            {
                     echo "Resultant Prime No:-", $myprimeAdd;
                     echo nl2br("\n");
                     break;
            }

        }

?>
```